# Função "change" com <ion-select><ion-option>

Tags: angular, ionic2, typescript

tudo bem? Estou com dificuldades, espero que possam me ajudar...
Estou estudando Ionic 2 a pouco tempo e pensei em fazer um aplicativo simples. No JavaScript consegui fazer tranquilamente, mas com Ionic não funciona. É o método onChange() que no ionic acredito que seja o ionChange (pelo que pesquisei), mas não consigo fazer funcionar.
Quero que ao selecionar a “raça”() “Humanos”() o console mostre uma mensagem “Deu certo”. Bem simples, mas não consigo.

HMTL:

```
<ion-list>
   <ion-item>
    <ion-label>Raças</ion-label>
      <ion-select id="racas" [(ngModel)]="racas" (ionChange)="teste();">
        <ion-option value="humanos">Humanos</ion-option>
        <ion-option value="anoes">Anões</ion-option>
        <ion-option value="elfos">Elfos</ion-option>
        <ion-option value="gnomos">Gnomos</ion-option>
        <ion-option value="meio-elfos">Meio-elfos</ion-option>
        <ion-option value="meio-orcs">Meio-orcs</ion-option>
        <ion-option value="halfling">Halfling</ion-option>
      </ion-select>
    </ion-item>
  </ion-list>
```

TS:

```
export class HomePage {
  public racas:string;

  teste(racas:string) {
    let x = (<HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById("racas")).value;
      if (x == "humanos") {
        console.log("Deu Certo!");
      }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Como você já está fazendo um `Two-way binding` em `racas`, basta acessá-la da seguinte forma:

```
export class HomePage {
  public racas:string;

  teste() {
      if (this.racas == "humanos") {
        console.log("Deu Certo!");
      }
  }
}
```

Veja funcionando no [plnkr](http://embed.plnkr.co/icSpgi/)

@edit

> Se eu não estivesse fazendo um bind, como ficaria?

Caso não estivesse o fazendo com `Two-way binding`, seria da seguinte forma utilizando o [`event binding`](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html#!#event-binding):

```
<ion-list>
   <ion-item>
    <ion-label>Raças</ion-label>
      <ion-select (ionChange)="teste($event);">
        <ion-option value="humanos">Humanos</ion-option>
        <ion-option value="anoes">Anões</ion-option>
        <ion-option value="elfos">Elfos</ion-option>
        <ion-option value="gnomos">Gnomos</ion-option>
        <ion-option value="meio-elfos">Meio-elfos</ion-option>
        <ion-option value="meio-orcs">Meio-orcs</ion-option>
        <ion-option value="halfling">Halfling</ion-option>
      </ion-select>
    </ion-item>
  </ion-list>
```

`HomePage.ts`

```
export class HomePage {
  teste(racas: any) {
      console.log(racas);
  }
}
```

Comment: Marcelo, muito obrigado! Funcionou na hora! Se eu não estivesse fazendo um bind, como ficaria?

Comment: Utilizando o `event binding`, adicionei à resposta.